# Multiple self referenced properties in Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I have a class that contains two navigation properties to itself.

```
public class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }    
    public Entity Parent { get; set; }    
    public Entity BaseEntity { get; set; }
}
```

When I run the application EF throws an expcetion which says
"Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'Test.Entity' and 'Test.Entity'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.".

As far as I Know, this exception is raised when a one-to-one relationship is being defined and no hints is provided for EF to determine both sides of the relation correctly.

Now I have two questions.

First, why is this exception raised here? Does EF consider this scenario as a one-to-one relationship somehow?

Second, how can I solve this problen using attributes?
I know the following Fluent API code solves the problem but I'm more comfortable with attributes.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>().HasOptional(e => e.Parent).WithOptionalDependent();
    modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>().HasOptional(e => e.BaseEntity).WithOptionalDependent();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an answer to my question on MSDN.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/08bba96a-20b2-4a3c-9e0e-a5475b703dfe/code-first-self-referencing-foreign-key?forum=adodotnetentityframework

And based on the approved answer (by Rowan Miller), the following code correctly describes the relationship (not my code).

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{         
    modelBuilder.Entity<AssetType>().HasOptional(a => a.parent).WithMany();
    modelBuilder.Entity<AssetType>().HasOptional(a => a.baseAssetType).WithMany();
}
```